# How to expand the exponential of a series?

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

I am wondering that for an exponent of a series like
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
f(n)=\exp[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{f_in^i}],
    \end{split}
\end{align}
if we expand it near $n \rightarrow0$, which is
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
f(n)&=1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{j!}\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{f_in^i}\Bigr)^j}\\
    &=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{g_i n^i}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
In general, can we describe the relationship between the coefficient of $f_i$ and $g_i$?

I tried to expand it with Mathematica, which turned out some patterns. In particular, the "$g_i$" is only determined by the first $i$ terms of $f_i$, and the relationship between them seems to be related to the factorial of "$i$" and some combinations. To be more specific, the $i$-th term $g_i$ depends on such a question: how to add to $i$? For example, the $4$-th term is
\begin{equation}
g_4=\frac{f_1^4}{4!}+\frac{f_{1}^2\ f_2}{2!\ 1!}+\frac{f_1 f_3}{1!\ 1!}+\frac{f_2^2}{2!}+\frac{f_4}{1!}
\end{equation}

However, I could not obtain the exact expression of the relationship between $f_i$ and $g_i$ even if I kind of believed it possible.

Besides, is it possible to obtain the convergence radius?

Comment: Try the [multinomial](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Multinomial/=). Also use exponential properties to create an infinite product

Comment: With appropriate factorial insertions you get what are called the Bell polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Generating_function

Comment: Interesting! I will read the material and think about it. Thank you very much!